# Run rails models without rails / make logger available globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have a rails application and want to run some part of it with less memory footprint. Thus I am trying to run these without Rails.

Everything(?) is `require`d, but the code crashes, when it reaches calls to `logger`.

Is there a way to either create a variable or method `logger`globally or add one to the scope of specific classes from the outside? I don't want to remove all logging from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `logger` method in `Object`:

```
class Object
  def logger
    -> { Logging.logger.root }.call
  end
end
```

Speak up if you have a better solution.